# How can i minus two Dates asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql, date-format

How can i  minus two Dates   (LblExpirydate.Text -  Label3.Text )

```
        LblExpirydate.Text = String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", dataReader(0))
        Label3.Text = System.DateTime.Now.ToString(("dd/MM/yyyy"))
```

LblExpirydate.Text = 01/05/2013

Label3.Text        = 01/04/2011

Answer (score 1):

You can subtract one date from another to get a TimeSpan. You should not try to do date calculations on strings: your program is likely to fall foul of an assumed date format somewhere.

```
Dim dateFormat As String = "dd/MM/yyyy"
Dim rightNow As DateTime = DateTime.Now

Dim expiryDate As DateTime = rdr.GetDateTime(0)

Dim daysToExpiry As Integer = (expiryDate - rightNow).Days

LblExpirydate.Text = expiryDate.ToString(dateFormat)
Label3.Text = expiryDate.ToString(dateFormat)
LabelExpires.Text = daysToExpiry.ToString & " days"
```